# How to download a csv file from django docker container

Tags: python, django, csv, docker-compose

I have an mounted django app using docker-compose. I also have generated a csv file in the server django app directory and inside the docker container.

server django directory

```
/restapi
|*filename.csv
|*app1
|*app2
```

inside docker container directory

```
/django
|*filename.csv
|*app1
|*app2
```

i already tried setting up a static absolute path for both server and docker directory, but i still couldn't download the csv file.

```
response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
django_root_path = '/django'

file_path = '{}/filename.csv'.format(django_root_path)
logger.info(file_path)
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=file_path'
response.write(u'\ufeff'.encode('utf8'))

return response
```

Comment: `myfilename.csv` is not the name of the file in your directory listing.  the `docker-compose.yml` and `Dockerfile` would also be useful here.

Comment: i edited the content, i removed the original filename in my code. there are no issue about the filename.